# horizontally align float items - width problem

Tags: html, css

On mobile, I'm looking to center `nav` items horizontally (I'm using float to horizontally layout items).  I'm trying

```
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

but instead of seeing this (which is what I want)

[image: Items are perfectly in a row]

I am seeing

[image: second and third items wrapped]

Is there an easy fix for this problem?

Update: I was able to by applying the following to the parent element of ul
{ text-align: center; width: 100%; }

Comment: Have you tried using `flex`?

Comment: I could not see `menu-item` nor `left:` in your code. Have you copied the correct code part?

Comment: best and easy way to responsive , use **Bootstrap**..

Comment: checkout- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Comment: @IvanDidyk  menu-item --> menu1, menu2 ... in code   i've applied float: left to .box li  (last line in code)

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox for solve problem

```
.box2 ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.box2 li {
    flex-grow: 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks but it's not exactly centering things.  i also tried justify content: space between - this should spread things out evenly I think, but didn't work either...

Comment: update: I was able to center things horizontally with:  .box2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}    Not sure if this is the right way, but it seems it's working